# Importing a 3D array from Matlab to R

Tags: r, matlab, multidimensional-array, file-conversion

I am trying to import a Matlab file into R for some analysis.  The matlab file is a 3D positional array of probability values. So, its a 2D (x,y) matrix across z "slices".  What I'd like to do is convert this into an R file that has the "location" and then the reported probability value. So something along the lines of the below as an output:

```
Prob    x    y    z
0.17    1    1    1
0.28    1    1    2
0.35    2    1    1
0.40    2    1    2
0.16    1    2    1
0.27    1    2    2
0.34    2    2    1
0.80    2    2    2
```

When I use the R.matlab package I can import the data, and it appears to import fine, but I can't seem to get the "dimensions" of the data or divide it into different matrices... or really do anything useful but have it appear as a long "list" of values that is the length of the rows*columns *slices.

Below is some example code:

Matlab Code

```
x = rand(3,4,2)
save file.mat x
```

R Code

```
Tdata <- readMat("file.mat") 
    head(Tdata)
    str(Tdata)
    length(Tdata$x)
```

Which outputs

```
> str(Tdata)
List of 1
$ x: num [1:3, 1:4, 1:2] 0.026 0.330 0.222 0.631 0.567 ...
- attr(*, "header")=List of 3
..$ description: chr "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Mon Dec  5 17:45:33 2016                                        "
..$ version    : chr "5"
..$ endian     : chr "little"

> length(Tdata$x)
[1] 24
```

So it shows that Tdata is a single element list containing an array with three dimensions, and each dimension is correct, and it has the right total number of values but I can't seem to separate out any of those lists or identify their dimensions using length() or dim() functions. Originally, I was thinking of using something like the below but because I can't get the dimensions it doesn't seem to work.

```
ndim <- dim(Tdata)
x_coord <- c(1:ndim[1])
y_coord <- c(1:ndim[2])
z_coord <- c(1:ndim[3])
    new_df <- expand.grid(x_coord,y_coord,z_coord)
    new_df <- cbind(new_df,Tdata$x)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you use Octave as an intermediary, `foreign::read.octave` can read in an array directly.

Comment: So I tried reading the .mat file in with read.octave("file.mat") and I get this error: 

Error in switch(type, matrix = read_octave_matrix(con), scalar = read_octave_scalar(con),  : 
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Then I tried reading the file in with data <- readMat("file.mat") and then reading that "data" with read.octave(data).  Then I tried converting "data" to an array, and reading that with read.octave.  None of those worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good point, I will update the text to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the `Tdata` object that is displayed you get to the array with `Tdata$x` or `Tdata[[1]]`. Unfortunately I am unaware of any equivalent to the matrix functions `row` and `col`. You can build the indices with a series of nested `rep`-calls.

```
rows = rep( rep( 1:dim(arr)[1], each=dim(arr)[3] ), times=dim(arr)[2])
cols= rep( rep( 1:dim(arr)[1], each=dim(arr)[3] ), each=dim(arr)[2])
instances= rep( rep( 1:dim(arr)[1], times=dim(arr)[3] ), times=dim(arr)[2])
```

Then this returns an object (hopefully, but untested in the absence of an example presented with `dput`-output.)

```
data.frame( Prob = Tdata$x, x=rows,y=cols, z=instances)
```

There is a functiuon that generates dataframes with rows containing unique combinations but you would need to call it with a lableing that might appear less intuitive:

```
> expand.grid( z = 1:dim(arr)[1], x = 1:dim(arr)[2], y = 1:dim(arr)[3])
  z x y
1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1
3 1 2 1
4 2 2 1
5 1 1 2
6 2 1 2
7 1 2 2
8 2 2 2
```

---

Old answer based on misreading of the question:

My `rd.txt` function just sets read.table arguments to read from text with a header to make a dataframe (and I made it before the `text`-argument was created for `read.table`):

```
> arr <- array(NA, c(2,2,2) )
> df <- rd.txt("Prob    x    y    z
+ 0.17    1    1    1
+ 0.28    1    1    2
+ 0.35    2    1    1
+ 0.40    2    1    2
+ 0.16    1    2    1
+ 0.27    1    2    2
+ 0.34    2    2    1
+ 0.80    2    2    2
+ ")
```

Now,  use the matrix-index method to address locations in an array (or more commonly a matrix):

```
> arr[ as.matrix(df[-1]) ] <- df[[1]]
> arr
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.17 0.16
[2,] 0.35 0.34

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.28 0.27
[2,] 0.40 0.80
```

The val, i, j format is also used by R's sparse matrix Matrix package (all hail to Martin Maechler).

Comment: I think you are doing the exact opposite of what I want to do. I want to go from a 3D matrix to a text file.  What I have is a 3D array of probabilities and I need to go to a text file (or csv or any standard format) which is the x,y,z coordinate (matrix position) and the probability at that matrix coordinate.

Comment: I will change the answer. It's much simpler.

Comment: The real problem is that I am having a problem importing the .mat file. As explained above, when I import the .mat file its a 3D array but I can't get any of its dimensions with functions I know of.  With no dimensions, I can't generate an index and assign values.  In reality I will be importing hundreds to thousands of these files and each will be a different size. So I need a way to identify the dimensions of an unknown array imported from matlab (dim(), length(), and nrow() or ncol() all just give values of 1) or to be able to access its indices and get values from every index location.

Comment: If you presented the output of `dput(Tdfata)` I would have something to work with. As it is I can only go by your error reports. At this point 'm guessing you would need to first assign to an object named `arr` with this code: `arr <- Tdata[[1]]`

Comment: AH! You are a genius. That was all I needed. Now arr is a normal array that I can call dim on and get dimensions.  Thank you for your help.  Now, for the indexing. These files will eventually be enormous, though the example is a small 3D array.  Do you know the most computationally efficient way to go from a 3D probability array to a 4 column (x,y,z,prob) matrix? Where x,y, and z are the array position and prob is the value at that position?

Comment: I think what I offered will be reasonably efficient for dense matrices. R also offers sparse matrices in the `Matrix` package. If you wnat to see how the Master craftmen constructed expand.grid, the code can be easily viewed. If you feel the "need for speed", you might might to look into the Rcpp or data.table packages. If the question is answered you might want to checkmark it. That act has benefits for you, me and the rest of SO.